# Cropping NP array quickly

Tags: python, numpy

I have an 2D NP array image that I want to chop off the left and right ends of the image. My plan is to run a smaller cropped image into a hough circle transform to speed up processing rather than using a full size image. What I noticed is that the cropping of the image is taking an extremely long time, especially when chopping from the front and back at the same time. In-fact, running the hough transform alone on the full size image is just as fast as cropping and running hough on the smaller image. The images are in the realm of 200x700 in size and I am chopping off up to 100-250 from front and back.

```
crop_image = img[:,crop_val:-crop_val]
```

The code above takes significantly longer to process than:

```
crop_image = img[:,crop_val:]
```

However, both are taking longer than I would have hoped. Is there a faster way to crop down an image for processing than indexing the way I am above?

Comment: does using `crop_image.copy()` make any difference in processing speed?

Comment: making a copy after cropping the image?

Comment: While the `img[:,crop_val:-crop_val]` makes a view, and should be fast, I don't know what's happening in the transformation.  It's just a **guess** that it might be faster if it worked on a copy rather than a view.

Comment: *"cropping of the image is taking an extremely long time"* I cannot reproduce your problem. In fact, `img[:,crop_val:-crop_val]` is indeed a view and actually a contiguous one assuming the array is contiguous. I think your input array is not contiguous and Numpy as no choice but copying the array which is not efficient compared to creating a view. If so, then you need to try to avoid non-contiguous arrays or merge multiple operations in one (possibly using Numba/Cython if Numpy cannot). Anyway, this is why you need to provide a *minimal reproducible example*.